# STM8 multi-byte I2C reads

Tags: c, i2c, stm8

```
u8 i2c_read_register(u8 mem_address, u8 *data_read)
{
    u8 temp = 0;
    u8 ack = 0;
    u8 device_address = (IQS_ADDR << 1);
    u8 polling_attempt = 0;

    // send address
    ack = i2c_send_byte(device_address);
#ifdef POLLING
    while ((ack) && (polling_attempt < POLLING_ATTEMPTS))
    {
        i2c_wait();
        i2c_wait();
        i2c_start();
        ack = i2c_send_byte(device_address);
        polling_attempt++;
    }
#endif
    if (!ack)
    {
        i2c_send_byte(mem_address);
        i2c_repeat_start();
        device_address = (IQS_ADDR << 1) | 0x01;
        ack = i2c_send_byte(device_address);
        temp = i2c_read_byte(1);
        (*data_read) = temp;
    }

    return ack;
}
```

- Notes 
  In order to read two Byes I need to call the function Like This:

  i2c_read_register(DEBUGGING_EVENTS, &data_buffer[1], 2);

With (2) representing the Number of Bytes.
But as the function stand it only takes two arguments not three.

Comment: Have you considered calling `i2c_read_byte()` twice?

Comment: @EJP Yes, but its not working accordingly

Comment: The Memory Address that I'm trying to read always return two bytes, First byte for Events, and 2nd Bytes for movement, so I have to specify reading the two bytes in my function.

Comment: As suggested - call i2c_read_byte() with the two different addresses you are trying to read from. If this doesn't work, it implies that the device is expecting a multi-byte read and the data is not valid if this is not the case (you should already have seen this in the datasheet). In this case, try Googling "i2c multi-byte read" and "i2c repeated start condition". This info is normally included as a simple timing diagram in the datasheet too.

Comment: @Stefan Dzisiewski-Smith, Yes your comment sound helpful, With function above I am able to read the 1st Byte which is the events. But according to the datasheet, the Register adress is always returning 2 bytes and the event bytes is always the 1st bytes. So the second bytes is there but I can't store it in a buffer because my function does not allow me to read the second buffer.

Comment: I2C registers are all 8-bits wide internally, so a single register can only return one byte. In cases where multiple bytes are required, they are stored across multiple registers. Take a look at the register map in the datasheet and look to see if you can work out where the data is actually coming from. A good guess would be the address immediately after the memory address you are currently reading - for example, if you are currently reading 0x1E, try looking in the datasheet to see if the second byte is in 0x1F.

Comment: @Stefan Dzisiewski-Smith , I got your point, my datasheed said "Each read instruction returns ‘EVENTS’ byte as first byte, followed by the data at the specified address" So my only problem is to be able to read 2 bytes, so that I can extract the 1st byte and the second bytes. Its worth Mentioning that I have achieved this with PIC18 and its not possible to port the function into the stm8, thats why I need a new function. The current function only read on bytes, that why ask if anyone can help me modify it to read to bytes.

Comment: OK - so this is really about STM8 multi-byte reads. I haven't worked with STM8 parts before, but a quick Google on this brought up ST application note AN3281. That looks worth a read - but the fact I found something that quickly suggests you have not done much research on this.

Comment: @ Stefan Dzisiewski-Smith already have that AppNotes open, the functions prototype is there, but some coding is needed to put the function together. I was looking for a quick fix. But I can definitely work it out. Thanks for your Help, Unlike those who have down-voted the Question without saying anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the software package for the stm8 Eval board is an example project which is using a serial eeprom which is able to read multiple bytes.

[sEE example software](https://github.com/VincentYChen/STM8teach/blob/master/code/Utilities/STM8S_EVAL/Common/stm8s_eval_i2c_ee.c)

Comment: Yes I do I have the file, as you may have noticed I already Have a function that was working but only for reading a single byte. So I only wanted to modify it to read two Bytes instead of writing a whole new Function.

Answer (score 0):

After Hours of Trying to modify the Code I finally managed to get the Specified two Bytes from my i2c_read_register() Function.

```
u8 i2c_read_register(u8 register_address, u8 *data_read, u8 NumbOfBytes)
{
    u8 i;
    u8 temp = 0;
    u8 ack = 0;
    u8 device_address = (IQS_ADDR << 1);
    u8 polling_attempt = 0;

    // send address
    ack = i2c_send_byte(device_address);
#ifdef POLLING
    while ((ack) && (polling_attempt < POLLING_ATTEMPTS))
    {
        i2c_wait();
        i2c_wait();
        i2c_start();
        ack = i2c_send_byte(device_address);
        polling_attempt++;
    }
#endif
    if (!ack)
    {
        i2c_send_byte(register_address);
        i2c_repeat_start();
        device_address = (IQS_ADDR << 1) | 0x01;
        ack = i2c_send_byte(device_address);
        //temp = i2c_read_byte(1);
        //(*data_read) = temp;
        if(NumbOfBytes > 1)
        {
            for(i = 0; i < NumbOfBytes -1; i++)
            data_read[i] = i2c_read_byte(0);
        }
        data_read[i] = i2c_read_byte(1);
    }

    return ack;
}
```

All That was needed, was to add a for Loop Incrementing the Number of Bytes to read as input by user with the u8 NumbOfBytes variable.

And you call the function Like This:

```
i2c_start();
i2c_read_register(DEBUGGING_EVENTS, &data_buffer[0], 2);
i2c_stop();                 
events = data_buffer[0];    // Main Events  1st Byte
movement = data_buffer[1];  // Debugging Events 2nd Byte
```

Comment: You might want to flag your own answer as correct, so that others know that this is now solved.

Comment: @ stefandz, Yes The u=rules says u have to wait for 48 Hours to Flag your own answer as solution.